# How to modify void class method so it returns the required information

Tags: java, class, types, return

I wrote a class that has a whole collection of static methods. One of my static methods accepts a string as an argument. I'm supposed to send a name to the method such as John Mike Baldibanga and its supposed to return a string containing only the initials of the first two names and the full last name.

so if I send John Mike Baldibanga to my method I want it to return 
J M Baldibanga.

So far I was only able to figure out how to get the method to work by using a void.

```
    public static void Theinitials(String z){

        String s []= z.split(" ");

                System.out.print(s[0].charAt(0) + " ");

                System.out.print(s[1].charAt(0)+ " ");
            System.out.println(s[2]);


    }
```

This is what I use to call the method presently:

String.Theinitials(name);

Comment: Get the println's out of the method. Instead return a String and let the calling code have the printlns in it.

Comment: Why is it necessary for the method to have `void` return type? `String` return type is suitable here.

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work. I tried to write String b = s[0].charAt(0) + " " + s[1].charAt(0)+ " " + s[2]; return b; but it didn't work

Comment: Sangharsh  I'm having a lot of trouble changing it to a String return type

Comment: `return s[0].charAt(0) + " " + s[1].charAt(0)+ " " + s[2];` should have worked. What was the error?

Comment: Also, you can not call Theinitials method with String class. You need to call it with the class name where this method is defined.

Comment: @RahulShah You can if you define your own `String` class.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, we can declare our String class, but then he does need to make the replace all the default class of String to java.lang.String to avoid namespace collision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it's supposed to return a string

So return a `String` instead of `void` and instead of `System.out.print`ing, build up a single `String result` and `return` that:

```
public static String theInitials(String z){
    String s []= z.split(" ");
    String result = s[0].charAt(0) + " " + s[1].charAt(0) + " " + s[2];
    return result;
}
```

Then print it later if that's what you need to do:

```
String initials = WhatEverYourClassIsCalled.theInitials(name);
System.out.println(initials);
```

From `String.Theinitials(name);` it looks like your class is called `String`. That might cause you some headaches, I would suggest renaming it.

Also notice how I called the method `theInitials`, this is called lowerCamelCase and is just [good practice](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) when naming methods and variables in Java.

Comment: Ok now I know why it wasn't working  I had entered String b == s[0].charAt(0) + " " + s[1].charAt(0) + " " + s[2]; but I had forgotten to change the method from void to String. What would I do without any smart people around? No idea...but thank you a whole bunch for helping out

Comment: Happy to help, don't forget to click the checkmark to accept the answer and the grey up arrow to vote up.

Answer (score 1):

A void method is a method with no return type.  I think you are trying to return a string,  Simply change the methods return type like so:

```
public static String Theinitials(String z){

    String s []= z.split(" ");
    String str;

    str = (s[0].charAt(0) + " ");
    str = (str + (s[1].charAt(0)+ " "));
    str = (str + s[2]);

    return str;
}
```

This should make a string str which will be made out of the string you would have exported to the console. You then return that string.

Answer (score 1):

> So far I was only able to figure out how to get the method to work by
>   using a void.

`void` is not supposed to return any value at all.

If you really want to know a method to work by using a void, declare a private static member in the class and assign the value to be returned to this static variable. [**Although this is not highly recommended but since you asked**]

Best choice is to let your method return `String` instead.